# Times in Chat Box in Rooms don't update

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, timestamps, chat-stars

The posts that are starred in chat go to a Chat Box (may have the terminology wrong here), but I noticed that the timestamps never update unless I hit reload.

How about we make them relative, so they stay accurate.

Comment: hmmm = ok; yes, maybe they should be *absolute*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Everloving balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) dynamicised the timestamps on starred messages a while ago.

As [quoted from chat on 2011-02-23:](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=528344#528344)

[image: the stars have changed, eat your fantales soon]